# Hot code replace failed - JSP + Eclipse + Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

When I edit a JSP, I get "Hot code replace failed" warning. The change is still visible in the browser.
I use Eclipse 2022-12 (4.26.0), Tomcat 9.0, Java 11 OpenJDK.

It does not happen with Jetty 9.4. According to Jetty/jasper documentation, Jetty uses JDK compiler if available. Does that mean that I should force Tomcat to use JDK compiler instead of ECJ compiler? How do I do that?

Comment: I doubt this does not happen with Jetty 9.4 for the same(!) edit in the same situation.

Comment: (1) Are you using Windows platform? (2) Are you debugging a page or class and not ending the debug?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes.

Answer (score 0):

You could also ignore this message. Tomcat is reloading the JSP all by itself, and eclipse tries to do it again. As you observe, the changed JSP is active, so there's nothing that eclipse could do for you additionally.